# How do I align multiple textures across a model with seamless results?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I was speaking with someone a while back who works in the gaming industry. I showed them this model and they noticed straight away that the texture was not connected in certain areas. Although this model only has one texture, I would like to know if there is a way of aligning multiple textures and keeping the normal mapping the same all the way around the model, To keep equal tessellation across the whole model using multiple textures? If there is way of achieving this in cycles it would be great.

In the link I have provided an image of the model I showed them outlining the issue

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Research UV unwrapping

Comment: ...maybe you forgot the "link"?